# JS: Seek command not seeking for music bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Seek command not working for the music bot, it's only replaying the song. The seek command was sospport to go to a time like 1:00 on the song if the user put it. I got no errors. Below is the code:

```js
 module.exports = {
    name : 'seek',
    description: 'Pick a time',
    usage : "<time>",
    run : async (client , message  , args) => {
const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
    let channel = message.member.voice.channel;
    if (!channel)return message.channel.send("Join a voice channel to play music!")
  if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send("No songs to seek");
  try {
    const curDuration = (serverQueue.songs[0].durationm * 60000) + ((serverQueue.songs[0].durations % 60000) * 1000);
    const choiceDur = args.join(" ").split(":");
    if (choiceDur.length < 2) return message.channel.send("No duration provided or invalid ?");
    const optDurr = (parseInt(choiceDur[0], 10) * 60000) + ((parseInt(choiceDur[1], 10) % 60000) * 1000);
    if (optDurr > curDuration) return message.channel.send("Your duration is too big");
    serverQueue.songs.splice(1, 0, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    return serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end()
  } catch (e) {
    return message.channel.send(`Oh no an error occured : \`${e.message}\` try again later`)
  }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

I tried
`serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.seek()`
`serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.seek(choiceDur)`
`serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end(choiceDur)`
`serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end()`

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you expand on your question and explain what you have already tried? It will help save people time when they attempt to help you.

Comment: Ok added @user230910

Comment: I dont see anywhere you put seek in your code

Answer (score 1):

To be clear `connection.dispatcher` is Stream follow [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher) there is no method called `seek()` or `end()`.

And to play song at specific times you should stop current streams and start new one at specific times.

Solution:

```
serverQueue.connection.play(serverQueue.currentSong, {seek: ms / 1000});
//serverQueue.currentSong is stream type
```

For more information: [VoiceConnection#play](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection?scrollTo=play) takes a second [StreamOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/StreamOptions) argument. **Note** type of streaming not every type can be seek